# Suppose $A \subseteq  C$ and $B$  and $C$ are disjoint. Prove that $x \in A \rightarrow x \notin B$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A \subseteq  C$ and $B$  and $C$ are disjoint. Prove that $x \in A \rightarrow x \notin B$.

Basically I need to prove this.

Comment: Not much to it: Since $A\subset C$, $a\in A\Rightarrow a\in C$. Since $C\cap B=\emptyset$, $a\in C\Rightarrow a\notin B$.

Comment: Since $x\in A$ and $A\subseteq C$ then ...; but $B$ and $C$ are disjoint, so ...

Answer (score 2):

In proving these things you need to show that no matter how $A,B,C$ look like, if the condition that $A\subseteq C$ and $B\cap C=\varnothing$ then $x\in A\rightarrow x\notin B$ is true.

For this we want to take an arbitrary element of $A$, use the definition that $A\subseteq C$ to deduce more about $x$; and use the definition of $B\cap C$ to deduce that if $x$ was in $B$ then the intersection would not be empty - therefore $x\notin B$.

I leave the formal and technical details to you, since this is *your* homework assignment after all.